# Is the initial ㅎ not pronounced sometimes?

Tags: pronunciation

Sometimes I could not hear the initial "h" sound in the character ㅎ. For example, when I learned a word 회전 (rotation) in Memrise today, it sounds like "we-jheon", and I could not hear any "h" sound.

(It is in the course *"2000 Essential Korean Words for Beginners"*, if you want to know. The link is [here](https://www.memrise.com/course/1801/2000-essential-korean-words-for-beginners-3/) but I forgot where the word is...)

However, when I tried hearing the same word in Google Translate, there was clearly the "h" sound.

That said, it happened in other words as well. When the word starts with ㅎ, sometimes I could not hear the "h" sound.

Is this regional variation or only me? Or possibly just a recording issue? It is very difficult to hear them apart at the elementary phase of language learning...

Comment: I clearly hear the ㅎ sound from [the 41th file found here](http://www.darakwon.co.kr/mp3/FileDown_kor2.asp?p_id=2541&pf_type=5). Nonetheless, it is a good question for language learners. I think that English and Korean speakers hear the ㅎ sound somewhat differently, but I have no resources that can support my idea.

Comment: @Klmo How did you find the file? I think what we are talking about is different. What I meant is a language course on Memrise, which coincidently has the same file name as your link. It is a course just with vocabulary. I'll add the link.

Comment: "2000 Essential Korean Words for Beginners" is a book, so the publisher usually provides the audio files. I have found the link on the publisher's website.

Comment: I do not think we are talking about different things. [The Memrise course image](https://static.memrise.com/img/400sqf/from/uploads/course_photos/9023_2000%20Korean%20Words.JPG) is just part of the [book cover](http://www.darakwon.co.kr/koreanbooks/BookView.aspx?BookID=8). Can you add the link for the audio file?

Comment: If what you heard was made by a TTS (text-to-speech) engine, it might have given you wrong sounds. Then, the question should relate to real and synthesized audios. Because I do not use Memrise, I cannot confirm whether Memrise uses recorded audios.

Comment: @Klmo I don't think it is TTS since the speech voice seems different by words. I could not find the word now in the course, sorry, but when I found it I will add.

Comment: This page has it: https://www.memrise.com/course/1801/2000-essential-korean-words-for-beginners-3/34/ I do not see any audio link there maybe because I am not a signed-in user.

Comment: Unless following some other sound, 회전 should (I think I can use the word _always_) start with a clear /h/ sound, but perhaps it is its voicelessness that makes it less audible.

Comment: @Klmo Thanks. It does not have an audio link. You must start the session to hear the sound.

Comment: I needed to sign up to hear [the sound](https://static.memrise.com/uploads/audio/32120324024256_315012_87ec2.mp3) and it sounded like 외잔. As you said, it was not a TTS sound. Her audios for some other words sound awkward, even worse than Google TTS. It is definitely better to use the book and its audio files provided by the publisher. The book has example sentences, too.

Comment: Not exactly the same question but possibly related: (1) Is 회오리길 also written as 외오리길 (as in [this song](http://blog.naver.com/PostView.nhn?blogId=dmb04296&logNo=221485958154&parentCategoryNo=&categoryNo=111&viewDate=&isShowPopularPosts=true&from=search)), and does this imply anything about the pronunciation? (2) Is 고요히 (ㅎ not at the beginning of the word)  pronounced like 고요이 (as in [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCLXlMbhMwg))?

Comment: @user23823 (1) No, 외오리 길 does not mean 회오리 길. 외오리 consists of 외- (alone, single) and 오리 (a thin and long piece). (2) Some people pronounce 고요히 as 고요이 although this ㅎ should be pronounced as *voiced h* (ɦ). The omission of the voiced h at the beginning of a syllable is not standard but [quite common](https://www.korean.go.kr/nkview/nknews/200507/84_6.html) right after a vowel. // There are more complex rules on the pronunciation of ㅎ. I mentioned only one for pronouncing a single word that starts with ㅎ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should not omit ㅎ at the beginning of a word: You may refer to [the table here](https://cktaiwan.tistory.com/50) (어두 means *the beginning of a word*; 그대로 means *as it is*).
Your experience suggests that *we should not use flawed flashcards*.

---

Her *wrong* pronunciation for [회전 (that sounds like 외잔)](https://static.memrise.com/uploads/audio/32120324024256_315012_87ec2.mp3) and some other words indirectly shows that her native language is English (or another language that is not Korean), since, for example, a British pronunciation of **Hw**ang Ho is ˈ**w**æŋ ˈhəʊ in the International Phonetic Alphabet (IPA); her ㅓ does not sound like Korean ㅓ.

Some recordings of the correct pronunciation for 회전 can be found [here](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/search?nation=eng&nationCode=6&mainSearchWord=%ED%9A%8C%EC%A0%84).

Google Translate should *not* be trusted because it often provides the *wrong* transcription and sometimes the *wrong* audio (and even *mistranslation*).

Comment: I usually don't hear to google translate tts, but I think wrong audio is rare: **mistranslation is everywhere**. Nowadays it became better, but never, _never_ believe KO-EN google translation.

Comment: Google Translate TTS lacks *natural tones*. Your mimicking its tones makes people think: "You sound like a machine." Their TTS engine even misinterprets some words to give the wrong sounds. For simple common words, mistranslation is less often found; thoughts on this must differ.